# I get in apple sign button ( Sign in with Apple error: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)")?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

this is code  I imported  AuthenticationServices and added sign with apple in signing & Capabillites in Xcode and on Certificates and ids
error
Sign in with Apple error: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)")

```
 @available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension LoginViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,     didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {


switch authorization.credential {
case let appleIdCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
    let userId = appleIdCredential.user

    if let _ = appleIdCredential.email, let _ = appleIdCredential.fullName {
        LoginViewController.email = appleIdCredential.email
        self.name = (appleIdCredential.fullName?.givenName)!
       showalertforregister()

        
    }else {
        showalertforregister()
    }
    
    break
    
case let passwordCredential as ASPasswordCredential:
    self.name = passwordCredential.user
    let password = passwordCredential.password

    showalertforregister()
    
    

    
    break
default:
    showalertforregister()
    break
}




}

 func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
// Handle error.
print("Sign in with Apple errored: \(error)")

let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Sign failed", comment: "") , message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:   NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: "") , style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```